# How do I parse html in an external file from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I feel like I should know this, but as I'm sitting down trying to access an html file from my Javascript I don't really know where to start. I am using jQuery so do I just want to use jQuery.ajax()?

The external html is a table with various premium values, stored on the same domain but in a separate directory. When a user enters their birth year previously in the form and selects whether or not they are male or female and a smoker or non-smoker, I return specific values based on their age.

In the table below if they were 21, male, non-smoker i'd want to return the value in the mns cell from row #id21.

```
<table id="premiumRateTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="age">Age Next Birthday</th>
            <th id="cover">Default Cover</th>
            <th id="mns">Male Non-smoker</th>
            <th id="ms">Male Smoker</th>
            <th id="fns">Female Non-smoker</th>
            <th id="fs">Female Smoker</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="id20">
            <td headers="age">20</td>
            <td headers="cover">$100,000</td>
            <td headers="mns">$108.99</td>
            <td headers="ms">$154.55</td>
            <td headers="fns">$44.31</td>
            <td headers="fs">$68.61</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="id21">
            <td headers="age">21</td>
            <td headers="cover">$150,000</td>
            <td headers="mns">$160.81</td>
            <td headers="ms">$229.15</td>
            <td headers="fns">$58.16</td>
            <td headers="fs">$77.48</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="id22">
            <td headers="age">22</td>
            <td headers="cover">$150,000</td>
            <td headers="mns">$139.37</td>
            <td headers="ms">$199.167</td>
            <td headers="fns">$58.28</td>
            <td headers="fs">$72.89</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="id23">
            <td headers="age">23</td>
            <td headers="cover">$150,000</td>
            <td headers="mns">$128.64</td>
            <td headers="ms">$183.59</td>
            <td headers="fns">$56.28</td>
            <td headers="fs">$72.89</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="id24">
            <td headers="age">24</td>
            <td headers="cover">$150,000</td>
            <td headers="mns">$121.94</td>
            <td headers="ms">$172.87</td>
            <td headers="fns">$58.29</td>
            <td headers="fs">$79.90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="id25">
            <td headers="age">25</td>
            <td headers="cover">$150,000</td>
            <td headers="mns">$112.56</td>
            <td headers="ms">$158.13</td>
            <td headers="fns">$61.11</td>
            <td headers="fs">$84.91</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the file

Comment: In what capacity do you need to parse it?  You can use any ajax method to get the raw emission from that request on the same domain.

Comment: Edited the question above

Comment: can you show the html tabel?

Comment: Bhushan: question updated above with the table.

Comment: Why do people always do this... People seem to do these round about ways of getting data like this... It would be better to interface with a JSON providing php script, not a raw html file.

Answer (score 4):

Load the table once (`$(document).ready()`) and add it to an invisible element at the end of the body.

```
var dummyDiv = $("<div id='dummyDiv'/>").css("display","none");
dummyDiv.load("otherpage.html #id"+age);
dummyDiv.css("display","none");
$("body").append(dummyDiv);
```

And then you can run this code from anywhere to get the values from that table.

```
var dummyDiv = $("#dummyDiv");
var valYouWant = "mns"; //example value to grab
var value = dummyDiv.find('td[headers="'+valYouWant+'"]').text();
//do whatever you'd like with 'value'
```

Comment: Can I store the result of jQuery.load() in a variable and then only display part of it depending on some conditions met in Javascript?

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what you want based on your revised question. Also, if you have no reason to store the data as an HTML table other than for this function, storing it as json may be easier to work with. (Again, depending on what you want to do with it). I will edit my answer to be more of what you're looking for.

Comment: @hyperdouche you can get part of that document like: 

`$("body").load("index.html #content");`

Comment: So instead of saving the whole html structure as a variable in the js, do you reckon I should only access it when all selections have been made in the form? I'm not exactly sure what '$([select display element])' refers to above.

Comment: See my edits. It wasn't clear to me what you wanted to do with the data after you fetched it.

Comment: Thanks Phil, working on this now... seems like the way to go. I'll mark the answer once i've finished getting it set up. Thanks for your help.